# using algebraic curves to approximate shapes?

Tags: real-analysis, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, approximation-theory

Here's an interesting variation on the problem of approximating a continuous function on a closed bounded interval using polynomials.

When can you approximate a shape on $\mathbb{R}^2$ using algebraic curves $p(x,y)=0$?

Feel free to share any related topics or papers!

A precise problem, although not the only problem:

For the image of any continuous injective function $f$ from the circle $S^1$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, does there exist a sequence of polynomials $p_i(x,y)$ such that the "distance" between $U_i=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\;|\;p_i(x,y)=0\}$ and $f(S^1)$ tends to $0$? The distance between bounded sets $B,C\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is defined as $\sup_{b\in B}d(b,C)+\sup_{c\in C}d(B,c)$.

Comment: How can there be a continuous bijection from $S^1$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, one is compact and the other is not right...

Comment: @RohanDidmishe sorry I meant injective function

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Hi, I just looked up what the Fourier description of a curve is. It provides a way to parametrise the curve as $(x(\theta),y(\theta))$. But I'm more interested in using an algebraic curve, which is described by a relation between the coordinates $x$ and $y$ themselves. Would Fourier descriptors be of assistance in the latter direction? Ideas are welcome! Thanks!